# "Undefined mixin 'box-sizing'", in rails, using compass-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sass

This is the error message:

```
Undefined mixin 'box-sizing'.
(in /var/www/site/spree/app/assets/stylesheets/store/neat/_neat.scss:3)
```

Conditions:

I'm using rails 4.0.2

I've installed the compass-rails gem, and run 'bundle'. I've also installed the gems "bourbon" and "neat".

Within 'site/spree/app/assets/stylesheets/mystylesheet.css.scss', I have this:

```
@import "bourbon/bourbon";
@import "neat/neat";
```

neat requires the mixin "box-sizing", provided by compass. However, the mixin just isn't being picked up.

I've tried adding @import "box-sizing", @import "compass/box-sizing"., @import "compass/css3/box-sizing"

None of those lines works: rails remains completely unable to access compass mixins.

This is my entire gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'mysql2'

group :development do
   gem 'better_errors'
   gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_21, :rbx]
   gem 'rails_layout'
end

group :development, :test do
   gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end


gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'bourbon'
gem 'neat'

gem 'spree', '2.1.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-1-stable'
```

Comment: Have you tried @import "compass/css3/box-sizing"; ? This works for me

Comment: Yes. Tried that. Error remains the same.

Comment: Are you sure the compass version you use has it? Maybe you need an alpha version, I usually do that.

Comment: Yes. It's documented here: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_sizing/

Comment: Have you restarted your rails server?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted my server.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? Encountering it also. Thanks!

Comment: I think I found my problem, I still had the default application.css which you should remove.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your syntax a little as the old style of calling `box-sizing` is deprecated now.
If you were calling it in old style `@include box-sizing(border-box)` then change it to `box-sizing: border-box;`It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should install your compass-sass in the `assets group`

> Add the compass-rails gem line to a group called :assets in your application's Gemfile (Rails 3.1+ users should already have the :assets group):

source: https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails

What @Fire-Dragon-DoL was saying is to check if the gem has the right version of compass that supports `box-sizing`

Comment: Rails 4 doesn't use the :assets group. Also I found a thread on SO in which the maintainer of compass-rails states that the gem is compatible with rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 has removed the assets group indeed (so if you have that line take it out).
I had the same issue as you and changing my compass-rails source in my gemfile solved it for me:

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails'
```

Then remove your Gemfile.lock file and regenerate it using the bundle command.

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle
```

Then inside my scss file I had:

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3/box-sizing";
```